# Using Jeditable, JQuery in asp.net website for in line editing

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-ajax, webforms, jeditable

I'm trying to use the Jeditable plugin along with Data Table in Jquery. I have retrieved the data from the database and displayed it. Now, I want to add the inline editing feature for a cell. I can only find the steps for the editing in an MVC application and not for a simple web forms application.

The aspx page is as follows:

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptBooks" runat="server">
  <HeaderTemplate>
    <table id="tblBookdet" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display">
      <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Book Name</th>
            <th>Image Path</th>
            <th>Description</th>

        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
  </HeaderTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
      <td><%# Eval("Name") %></td>
      <td><%# Eval("Imagepath") %></td>
      <td><%# Eval("Desc") %></td>

    </tr>
  </ItemTemplate>
  <FooterTemplate>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {

           $('#tblBookdet').dataTable({
               "oLanguage": { "sSearch": "Search the Records:" },
               "iDisplayLength": 10,
               "aaSorting": [[0, "asc"]]

           });

           $('table#tblBookdet').dataTable().makeEditable({
           sUpdateURL: "Test.aspx"
           });

         });
</script>
```

The Page I have redirected to, has the following code just to see what is happening where "temp" is a label on the page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var postedvalues = Request.Form;
        string key;
        key = postedvalues["columnName"];

        temp.Text = key;
    }
```

I have also read that an AJAX post method is called on the press of the enter key after modifying the text. How am I supposed to catch the values returned in that(in my case, the Test.aspx page)?